# The story of Ajamila

Tags: karma, bhagavata-purana

> Ajamila the hero of the 6th Canto of Bhagavata Purana, in fright of the 3 Yamaduttas called the name of his son Narayana

Source- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajamila
To utter the name of the Lord one should have done a lot of good deeds, One must have done soo much Punya to utter "Narayana", Ajamila being a Brahmin led a Adharmic life, How was he able to utter the name of the Lord, Was his past deeds or karma described in Bhagavata Purana as how was he able to get compassion of God?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below verses are self explanatory.

> That old man Ajāmila had ten sons, of whom the **youngest was a baby
> named Nārāyaṇa.** Since Nārāyaṇa was the youngest of all the sons, he
> was naturally very dear to both his father and his mother. Because of
> the child’s broken language and awkward movements, old **Ajāmila was
> very much attached to him.** He always took care of the child and
> enjoyed the child’s activities. When Ajāmila chewed food and ate it,
> he called the child to chew and eat, and when he drank he called the
> child to drink also. **Always engaged in taking care of the child and
> calling his name, Nārāyaṇa,** Ajāmila could not understand that his
> own time was now exhausted and that death was upon him. When the time
> of death arrived for the foolish Ajāmila, he began **thinking
> exclusively of his son Nārāyaṇa**. When he saw them he was extremely
> bewildered, and because of attachment to his child, who was playing a
> short distance away, Ajāmila began to call him loudly by his name.
> Thus with **tears in his eyes he somehow or other chanted the holy
> name of Nārāyaṇa**.(SB 6.1.24-28)
>
> My dear King, the order carriers of Viṣṇu, the **Viṣṇudūtas,
> immediately arrived when they heard the holy name of their master from
> the mouth of the dying Ajāmila**, who had certainly chanted without
> offense because he had chanted in complete anxiety.(SB 6.1.30)
>
> The Viṣṇudūtas continued: Even previously, while eating and at other
> times, this **Ajāmila would call his son, saying, “My dear Nārāyaṇa,
> please come here.” Although calling the name of his son, he
> nevertheless uttered the four syllables nā-rā-ya-ṇa. Simply by
> chanting the name of Nārāyaṇa** in this way, he sufficiently atoned
> for the sinful reactions of millions of lives.Simply by chanting the
> holy name of Lord Viṣṇu, such sinful persons may **attract the
> attention of the Supreme Lord, who therefore considers, “Because this
> man has chanted My holy name, My duty is to give him protection.”**
> (SB 6.2.8-9)

Comment: This is soo nyc